# Does “one” always imply a number, or can “one" function as an emphasized “a"?

Tags: indefinite-article

Does “one” always imply a number, or can “one" function as an emphasized “a"? Examples: Take a cake, take one, a nice one! Take ONE (implying a number less than two)! In the first example, "take one" is pronounced with almost no pause between “take" and “one”. Am I correct in suggesting that “take a cake” and “take one” means exactly the same?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are correct.

**One** can act both as a pronoun and a number.

In the example you give, **take one** means **take a cake** rather than limit yourself to a single cake; that's unless the speaker emphasises **one** as a parent might do to a child.

We often say things like:

> If you come across a bottle of sparkling water in the shop will you get one for me?

Here **one** means a bottle of water and saves the speaker from repeating the phrase.

And:

> One should scrape the mud from one's shoes before entering the house.

In this case, we understand **one** to mean **a person**, any person rather than a particular person.